# react native - zooming in on image always zooms to the center, not where user points fingers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on displaying an image in React native.
I'm using `react-native-gesture-handler` and the native `Animated` component from react-native.

The image should be pinchable for zooming, and also panable to be able to move around once it's zoomed in. Everything works as expected, except it always zooms to the center, and I can't figure out a good way to use the focal points to actually update the X and Y while zooming and moving.

the `handlePinchStateChange` function gets run on each event change. If we start zoom, we can get get the focal points from the event argument

```js
const handlePinchStateChange = (event) => {
  console.log(event.nativeEvent.focalX, event.nativeEvent.focalY)
}
```

That's all good and all, but I need to use these values to update the X and Y in real time, not after the event which will happen if I just

```js
translateX = event.nativeEvent.focalY
```

How can I go about making both the panning AND pinching use the focal points, so that it zooms and moves towards where the user has their fingers?

Working snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@sbv/bold-chip

Working code:

```js
  const pinchRef = React.createRef();
  const panRef = React.createRef();
  const [panEnabled, setPanEnabled] = React.useState(false);

  const translateX = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const translateY = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const scale = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;

  const onPanEvent = Animated.event(
    [
      {
        nativeEvent: {
          translationX: translateX,
          translationY: translateY,
        },
      },
    ],
    {
      useNativeDriver: false,// cannot use nested native drivers in a snack
    }
  );

  const onPinchEvent = Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { scale } }], {
    useNativeDriver: false, // cannot use nested native drivers in a
  });

  const handlePinchStateChange = (event) => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {
      setPanEnabled(true);
    }

    if (event.nativeEvent.scale < 1) {
      Animated.spring(scale, {
        toValue: 1,
        useNativeDriver: true,
        bounciness: 2,
      }).start();
      Animated.spring(translateX, {
        toValue: 0,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
      Animated.spring(translateY, {
        toValue: 0,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
      setPanEnabled(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView>
      <PanGestureHandler
        ref={panRef}
        onGestureEvent={onPanEvent}
        enabled={panEnabled}
        simultaneousHandlers={[pinchRef]}>
        <PinchGestureHandler
          onGestureEvent={onPinchEvent}
          onHandlerStateChange={handlePinchStateChange}
          simultaneousHandlers={[panRef]}
          ref={pinchRef}>
          <Animated.Image
            source={{
              uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
            }}
            style={{
              width: '100%',
              height: 300,

              transform: [
                { scale },
                { perspective: 200 },
                { translateX: translateX },
                { translateY: translateY },
              ],
              resizeMode: 'contain',
            }}
          />
        </PinchGestureHandler>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi I try the same solution with the same result.
Reading the "react-native-gesture-handler" documentation and examples I make this component and works well.

```
import React, { useRef, createRef } from "react";
import { View, Animated, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import {
  PanGestureHandler,
  PinchGestureHandler,
  State
} from "react-native-gesture-handler";

export interface ImageWithZoomAndPanProps {
  imageURI: string;
}

const ImageWithZoomAndPan = ({ imageURI }: ImageWithZoomAndPanProps) => {
  const pinchRef = createRef();
  const panRef = createRef();

  /* Pinching */
  const baseScale = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;
  const pinchScale = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;
  const scale = useRef(Animated.multiply(baseScale, pinchScale)).current;
  let lastScale = 1;

  const onPinchGestureEvent = Animated.event(
    [
      {
        nativeEvent: {
          scale: pinchScale
        }
      }
    ],
    { useNativeDriver: true }
  );

  const handlePinchStateChange = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    if (nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {
      lastScale *= nativeEvent.scale;
      baseScale.setValue(lastScale);
      pinchScale.setValue(1);
    }
  };

  /* Pan */
  const translateX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const translateY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  let lastOffset = { x: 0, y: 0 };

  const onPanEvent = Animated.event(
    [
      {
        nativeEvent: {
          translationX: translateX,
          translationY: translateY
        }
      }
    ],
    { useNativeDriver: true }
  );

  const handlePanStateChange = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    if (nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {
      lastOffset.x += nativeEvent.translationX;
      lastOffset.y += nativeEvent.translationY;

      translateX.setOffset(lastOffset.x);
      translateX.setValue(0);
      translateY.setOffset(lastOffset.y);
      translateY.setValue(0);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <PanGestureHandler
        ref={panRef}
        onGestureEvent={onPanEvent}
        onHandlerStateChange={handlePanStateChange}
        shouldCancelWhenOutside
      >
        <Animated.View style={[styles.wrapper]}>
          <PinchGestureHandler
            ref={pinchRef}
            simultaneousHandlers={panRef}
            onGestureEvent={onPinchGestureEvent}
            onHandlerStateChange={handlePinchStateChange}
          >
            <Animated.View style={styles.imageContainer} collapsable={false}>
              <Animated.Image
                style={[
                  styles.pinchableImage,
                  {
                    transform: [
                      { scale: scale },
                      { translateX },
                      { translateY }
                    ]
                  }
                ]}
                source={{ uri: imageURI }}
              />
            </Animated.View>
          </PinchGestureHandler>
        </Animated.View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ImageWithZoomAndPan;


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%"
  },
  imageContainer: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    backgroundColor: "black",
    overflow: "hidden",
    alignItems: "center",
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  pinchableImage: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%"
  },
  wrapper: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
```